# Diffie Hellman Authentication Between PHP Server and .NET client

Tags: c#, php, .net, encryption, diffie-hellman

My desktop software is written in C# and the server that hosts my API is written in PHP. I am atempting to implement Diffie-Hellman key sharing so we can generate shared secrets and securely encrypt communications between our clients  and server.

I can generate the public and private keys on both ends, but I'm not sure what format to send the keys in on their way from the client to the server. **Code to create my keys in C#:**

```
    class DiffieHellman
    {
        private Aes aes = null;
        private ECDiffieHellmanCng diffieHellman = null;
        private readonly byte[] publicKey;
        private string pkce;
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public DiffieHellman()
        {
            this.aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            this.diffieHellman = new ECDiffieHellmanCng()
            {
                KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash,
                HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256,
            };

            this.publicKey = this.diffieHellman.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
        }


        public async Task sendKey()
        {

            byte[] key = this.publicKey;
            string base64EncodedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "key", base64EncodedKey }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("API_URL", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        }

    }
```

The issue here is that the key is formatted as a byte array so after I base64 decode it on my PHP server, I can't read the key and generate the shared secret. I've also tried converting the byte array to hex and sending it that way. **PHP using elliptic-php library:**

```
        $ec = new EC('curve25519');
        $senderPublicKey = $_POST["key"];

        // Generate keys
        $testKey1 = $ec->genKeyPair();
        $testKey2 = $ec->genKeyPair();

        //Generate shared key with testKey2 to verify library can generate common secret
        $shared1 = $testKey1->derive($testKey2->getPublic()); 
        echo $shared1->toString(16); //5986d466388b3b0e25cd8270659d81efe6d0696b1a8d983241a6d8da543203fb

        //Generate shared key with the public key sent by the client
        $shared2 = $testKey2->derive($senderPublicKey);  
        echo $shared2->toString(16); //nothing is echoed
```

I understand that they keys generated in C# are of the BCRYPT_ECCPUBLIC_BLOB structure, **but how would I convert this to a PHP-readable format?**

Comment: Are you not getting any errors? The `derive` method expects either a `KeyPair` object or a `BigNumber` (`BN`) object, a base64-encoded string is neither.

Comment: Is this for production use?  If so - why on earth are you not using TLS?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the byte array as JSON to your API, deserialize it and supply it to the `BigNumber` constructor:

```
$senderPublicKeyByteArray = json_decode($_POST['key']);   // [10, 42, 9, ...] byte array
$senderPublicKey = new BN($senderPublicKeyByteArray);
```